# IdentityServer4 post-login redirect not working in Edge browser

Tags: microsoft-edge, identityserver4

I am trying to set up a new instance of IdentityServer4 and started with the quickstart documentation to build the server.  I tested this with the provided MVC implicit and hybrid client apps.  Without modifying any of the code I am seeing an issue when running the client in Edge.  I can successfully login but the post-login redirect back to the client doesn't work.  Instead of going back to the client using the configured return url, the browser stops at the connect/authorize/callback url within identity server.  The url it is sitting at is:

http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=mvc&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5002%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj&state=CfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=2.1.4.0

This works in Chrome and IE, but not Edge.  Is there a fix or workaround for this?

Here is the identity server log output:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\aakoehle\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
info: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      You are using the in-memory version of the persisted grant store. This will store consent decisions, authorization codes, refresh and reference tokens in memory only. If you are using any of those features in production, you want to switch to a different store implementation.
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\Temp\IdentityServer4 Test\IdentityServerQuickstart
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 232.4112ms 200 application/json; charset=UTF-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 88.7646ms 200 application/json; charset=UTF-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize?client_id=mvc&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5002%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj&state=CfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=2.1.4.0
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
info: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
      {
        "ClientId": "mvc",
        "ClientName": "MVC Client",
        "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
        "AllowedRedirectUris": [
          "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc"
        ],
        "SubjectId": "anonymous",
        "ResponseType": "code id_token",
        "ResponseMode": "form_post",
        "GrantType": "hybrid",
        "RequestedScopes": "openid profile",
        "State": "CfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis",
        "Nonce": "636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj",
        "Raw": {
          "client_id": "mvc",
          "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
          "response_type": "code id_token",
          "scope": "openid profile",
          "response_mode": "form_post",
          "nonce": "636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj",
          "state": "CfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis",
          "x-client-SKU": "ID_NET",
          "x-client-ver": "2.1.4.0"
        }
      }
info: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator[0]
      Showing login: User is not authenticated
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 135.6793ms 302
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/account/login?returnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3Dmvc%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A5002%252Fsignin-oidc%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26nonce%3D636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj%26state%3DCfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis%26x-client-SKU%3DID_NET%26x-client-ver%3D2.1.4.0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (IdentityServerQuickstart) with arguments (/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=mvc&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5002%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj&state=CfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=2.1.4.0) - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ViewResult, running view at path /Views/Account/Login.cshtml.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (IdentityServerQuickstart) in 3421.3172ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 3608.1416ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/account/login?returnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3Dmvc%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A5002%252Fsignin-oidc%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26nonce%3D636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj%26state%3DCfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis%26x-client-SKU%3DID_NET%26x-client-ver%3D2.1.4.0 application/x-www-form-urlencoded 1005
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (IdentityServerQuickstart) with arguments (IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.LoginInputModel, login) - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[10]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv signed in.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.RedirectResultExecutor[1]
      Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /connect/authorize/callback?client_id=mvc&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5002%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj&state=CfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=2.1.4.0.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (IdentityServerQuickstart) in 108.0871ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 135.8729ms 302
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=mvc&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5002%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj&state=CfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=2.1.4.0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was successfully authenticated.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was successfully authenticated.
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint for /connect/authorize/callback
info: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint[0]
      ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
      {
        "ClientId": "mvc",
        "ClientName": "MVC Client",
        "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
        "AllowedRedirectUris": [
          "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc"
        ],
        "SubjectId": "2",
        "ResponseType": "code id_token",
        "ResponseMode": "form_post",
        "GrantType": "hybrid",
        "RequestedScopes": "openid profile",
        "State": "CfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis",
        "Nonce": "636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj",
        "SessionId": "2274bd4043d859abdf8643c798ac9dd4",
        "Raw": {
          "client_id": "mvc",
          "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
          "response_type": "code id_token",
          "scope": "openid profile",
          "response_mode": "form_post",
          "nonce": "636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj",
          "state": "CfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis",
          "x-client-SKU": "ID_NET",
          "x-client-ver": "2.1.4.0"
        }
      }
info: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator[0]
      Showing consent: User has not yet consented
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 103.6818ms 302
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/consent?returnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3Dmvc%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A5002%252Fsignin-oidc%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26nonce%3D636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj%26state%3DCfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis%26x-client-SKU%3DID_NET%26x-client-ver%3D2.1.4.0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was successfully authenticated.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was successfully authenticated.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[1]
      Authorization was successful for user: bob.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.ConsentController.Index (IdentityServerQuickstart) with arguments (/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=mvc&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5002%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj&state=CfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=2.1.4.0) - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ViewResult, running view at path /Views/Consent/Index.cshtml.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.ConsentController.Index (IdentityServerQuickstart) in 359.282ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 426.8066ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/lib/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was successfully authenticated.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was successfully authenticated.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/lib/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff'. Physical path: 'C:\Temp\IdentityServer4 Test\IdentityServerQuickstart\wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 67.508ms 200 application/font-woff
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/consent application/x-www-form-urlencoded 1085
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was successfully authenticated.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was successfully authenticated.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[1]
      Authorization was successful for user: bob.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.ConsentController.Index (IdentityServerQuickstart) with arguments (IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.ConsentInputModel) - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.RedirectResultExecutor[1]
      Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /connect/authorize/callback?client_id=mvc&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5002%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj&state=CfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=2.1.4.0.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.ConsentController.Index (IdentityServerQuickstart) in 69.8132ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 122.6652ms 302
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=mvc&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5002%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj&state=CfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=2.1.4.0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was successfully authenticated.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was successfully authenticated.
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint for /connect/authorize/callback
info: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint[0]
      ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
      {
        "ClientId": "mvc",
        "ClientName": "MVC Client",
        "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
        "AllowedRedirectUris": [
          "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc"
        ],
        "SubjectId": "2",
        "ResponseType": "code id_token",
        "ResponseMode": "form_post",
        "GrantType": "hybrid",
        "RequestedScopes": "openid profile",
        "State": "CfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis",
        "Nonce": "636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj",
        "SessionId": "2274bd4043d859abdf8643c798ac9dd4",
        "Raw": {
          "client_id": "mvc",
          "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
          "response_type": "code id_token",
          "scope": "openid profile",
          "response_mode": "form_post",
          "nonce": "636680636912464869.MzY4MTMwYjUtMDZkNi00ZTkxLTg0YWYtMTkzNmU1NjBjY2Q0NzMwMmQ2NjktZjQ3MC00NWZjLTk1YWMtNGJiMjcxNTRiZDVj",
          "state": "CfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis",
          "x-client-SKU": "ID_NET",
          "x-client-ver": "2.1.4.0"
        }
      }
info: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator[0]
      User consented to scopes: openid, profile
info: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint[0]
      Authorize endpoint response
      {
        "SubjectId": "2",
        "ClientId": "mvc",
        "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
        "State": "CfDJ8Ilv3xRREYlBnZpErV6qeZ4ppGT5lLwC5pDwHLAEtHGL8GccFuLXiDYvuQVGYRJMWPKM44sdcEfbSl33uhsLoH6BaYKsPuByeRjAbMXg4toFyrxEfOXuBFtVF25Yo4dAWQ0EhG9rr9PUjMJe8jcHMhI0FbDRpQnYg1eAAQm0iel1hnlu7DSVppnSpFuZlCSOyjGeus7oB_1Vys7MkTta_3ewZV8Sh6n9-P1sF6-V5U6Nh7zH2qLXJD-v7aGzfe117-dNYbaS32fIktmQMwEmORgJH_1kMmkdAefMMyRdV6vGHt7dI5MYpVHE5Ouqq1q0NBN3Dk00PvSrT6C2lLWLsis",
        "Scope": "openid profile"
      }
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[10]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv signed in.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 303.3942ms 200 text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more testing with this, checked the network traffic in the F12 debugger in Edge and saw some console errors.  There were several errors logged related to Content Security Policy (CSP).  Searching on that I found an older issue reported in the IdentityServer4 Git project, [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/475).  The comments on that issue explain the problem and also provide a solution to fix it, basically I needed to add some code to the Startup.cs Configure method to set a header to get around the CSP issue.